# With Qt Creator FakeVim mode, key-combination CTRL+U seem to interfere with "Select the current block"

Tags: qt, vim, qt-creator, fakevim

I'm starting to use QT creator and FakeVim mode. Inside VIM I use CTRL+U (Scroll window Upwards in the buffer) and CTRL+D (Scroll window Downwards in the buffer) the whole time.

Problem: CTRL+D works as expected inside QT creator, but unfortunately the key-combination CTRL+U seem to interfere with some other setting (maybe "Select the current block") and begins marking a lot of text at the same time it's scrolling upwards.

1. So: CTRL+D = scrolls down, no "block selecting"-stuff going on.
2. CTRL+U scrolls up and at the same time it begins highlighting (block selection), which is really annoying.

Attempted: Among other things, I tried googling and found: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html - and tried both combinations of the value "Enable smart selection changing" - but it ditn't help on my CTRL+U-issue...

Question: Anyone knows how I can make CTRL+U only scroll up, instead of selecting/highlighting a block while it scrolls up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record (it seems we're not many qtcreator/fakevim users but hopefully it can help someone else that) I found the solution and will answer myself:

First: Related to the issue is: In the "Options -> FakeVim -> General" dialog, under "Vim Behaviour" disable "Use search dialog" will get rid of (a similar) annoying vim-search "begin highlighting after search"-problem which is triggered when using "/" to search...

For the CTRL+U highlighting issue: The issue is resolved by disabling the option "Pass control keys" in the same option setting dialogue.